# Cannot install keras on Jetson nano

Tags: nvidia

I am running this command on Nvidia Jetson nano, running Ubuntu:

```
sudo pip3 install keras
```

And I get this error:

```
The directory '/home/jetson/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/jetson/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting keras
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/fd/6bfe87920d7f4fd475acd28500a42482b6b84479832bdc0fe9e589a60ceb/Keras-2.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (377kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 464kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from keras)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in /home/jetson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from keras)
Collecting h5py (from keras)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/97/a58afbcf40e8abecededd9512978b4e4915374e5b80049af082f49cebe9a/h5py-2.10.0.tar.gz (301kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 307kB 472kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /home/jetson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from keras)
Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 (from keras)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6a/8c1f62c37212d9fc441a7e26736df51ce6f0e38455816445471f10da4f0a/Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 736kB/s 
Collecting scipy>=0.14 (from keras)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/5c/495190b8c7cc71977c3d3fafe788d99d43eeb4740ac56856095df6a23fbd/scipy-1.3.3.tar.gz (23.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 23.8MB 20kB/s 
Collecting keras-applications>=1.0.6 (from keras)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e3/19762fdfc62877ae9102edf6342d71b28fbfd9dea3d2f96a882ce099b03f/Keras_Applications-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (50kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 722kB/s 
Installing collected packages: h5py, keras-preprocessing, scipy, keras-applications, keras
  Running setup.py install for h5py ... done
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-trv7zrqv/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7_rwoepq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    Running from scipy source directory.
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /home/jetson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /home/jetson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-trv7zrqv/scipy/setup.py", line 505, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-trv7zrqv/scipy/setup.py", line 501, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/home/jetson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 137, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-trv7zrqv/scipy/setup.py", line 403, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError(msg)
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-trv7zrqv/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7_rwoepq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-trv7zrqv/scipy/
```

What do I do wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall keras with `sudo pip3 uninstall keras` and run the following command in Ubuntu 18.04 and later to install keras from the default Ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo apt install python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-h5py python3-six python3-theano python3-yaml python3-keras
```

This is the long form of the command in order to show what packages are installed as dependencies of python3-keras. The short form of the same command is:

```
sudo apt install python3-keras
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall keras and try installing the dependencies(scipy first)

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libatlas-base-dev gfortran
```

If possible installing everything from [nano zoo](https://elinux.org/Jetson_Zoo) in the order that they have given because they ask you to install tensorflow first and then only keras. Worst case try flashing again and installing from zoo.